# Footnotes created via script appear in a strange location

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm writing a script to handle some layout and I've come across some odd behaviour when creating footnotes.

Whenever I create the footnotes with the script, they appear *before* the next paragraph which is of a different style to the paragraph containing the footnote. Unless it reaches the end of the story in which case they will appear at the bottom of the page.

I would like for it to behave the same way as when you insert a footnote via the menu, I.E. placing the footnotes together at the bottom of the page.

Here's a before and after:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Here's the relevant code which creates the footnotes. `references` is an array containing the superscript references in the text (as a `character` or range of `character` objects). `footnotes` is an array containing the footnotes between the `#FootnoteB` and `#FootnoteE` tags as `paragraph` objects.

```
for (var i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {
    // Create footnote
    newFootnote = textPara.parentStory.footnotes.add(LocationOptions.BEFORE, references[i].insertionPoints[0]);

    // Move footnote text into the footnote
    footnotes[i].move(LocationOptions.AFTER, newFootnote.insertionPoints[-1]);

    // Remove \r at the end of the footnote
    newFootnote.characters.item(-1).remove();

    // Delete the leftover superscript reference
    references[i].remove();
}
```

It seems to make no difference *where* I add the footnotes, whether I add them to the paragraph, story or text frame, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the paragraph styles that appear after the footnotes for their ParagraphStyle.spanColumnType value. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but if your paragraph spans columns the footnote will appear above it (as if it were the beginning of a new column).

Through the UI, you can check this by editing the paragraph style and checking its Span Columns tab.

ETA: the values you would want in order to avoid the footnote placement you have now are SpanColumnTypeOptions.SINGLE_COLUMN or, via the UI, just Single Column.